# Drupal 9 SQL Server connection error upon installing locally

Tags: sql-server, drupal

As per multiple documents I am able to configure the SQL Server and copy drivers to `ext` folder
Now when I am trying to install Drupal I am getting an error

Resolve all issues below to continue the installation. For help configuring your database server, see the installation handbook, or contact your hosting provider.

> Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
> Is the database server running?
> Does the database exist, and have you entered the correct database name?
> Have you entered the correct username and password?
> Have you entered the correct database hostname?

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jN8T.jpg)

I have only added a username for the password used blank for the default installation of SQL.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: So why is it trying to use the Named Pipes provider instead of TCP/IP? What's the host operating system? What set of drivers did you install (including the package download versions/URLs for ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server)? What did you actually enter into the `host`, `port` and `prefix` fields in the Drupal configuration panel?